# Users are able to register apps that look official (for phishing)

Tags: bug, api, security, abuse

Recently, a user was [able to register an app with the name "StackOverflow"](https://stackapps.com/q/8280/7653).
Alarmed, I tried it myself.

If you click [this authorization link](https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=14710&scope=no_expiry,read_inbox,private_info,write_access&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success), you will see:

[image: real bad]

... which sure **looks official.**

This is ripe for mischief, phishing, and worse.

---

The [registration page](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) has a `placeholder` attribute that says:

> Be Unique! **Avoid implying an official Stack Exchange relationship**

<sup>(Emphasis added.)</sup>

But, that didn't stop that user (nor myself) from creating a misleading app name.

**The authorization page should identify it as a third party app regardless.**

---

Note that there is [**an additional bug**](https://stackapps.com/questions/8283/the-authentication-doc-gives-a-wrong-domain-for-authentication) whereby the page seems to be for Stack Overflow, but the app is **really being authorized for all Stack Exchange sites**<sup>‡</sup>.

---

## Recommendations:

1. The authorization page should make clear that they are authorizing a **third party app**.
2. Official Stack Overflow/Exchange/etc. **logos should not appear to belong to the third party app**.
3. App names, like **"Stack Overflow", etc. should be automatically blocked** from registration.  But official names part of a longer string should be okay.  EG: "Stack Overflow comment filter".
4. The App's **description should also be shown** on the authorization page (and not allowed to be blank).

---

‡ Except for *Area51*. Teams also has a bit different behavior -- at least for me.

Comment: What happens if you use the name “Stack Overflow” (with space) as per the brand guidelines a space is required?

Comment: Well, the user who did it should be suspended for a while, that's for sure.

Comment: Yes, not following the brand guidelines is a hanging offense.

Answer (score 16):

I quite like GitHub's OAuth login screen, which I think we could take ideas from (if you want to see it yourself, try using [Login-with](https://login-with.com/login) for an example):

> [image: GitHub OAuth login screen]

Here it *clearly* states that it's not operated by GitHub which is the most important thing.

It also tells the user what to expect after clicking the authorise button (the redirect), which I think is pretty useful because I know a lot of users have no idea what to expect -- since developers can set whatever redirect URL they want, they could be redirected to a domain the end-user has never seen before!

Whilst we're at it, it would also be nice to mention that the user can, *at any time*, revoke access and a link to a help page or the apps page would be useful. Because right now, that screen is hidden away in the user profile on the `/users/apps/id` page (`/current` at the end doesn't work `:(`)